# Having problems with returning specific rows with node mysql (Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm currently developing a private Discord Bot but I'm having problems with node mysql returning a specific row. What I'm trying to do is when I use the command for example **!dbreturn Dave**, the bot should return all queries from the Dave row.

*Here's my code:*

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, con) => {

    var name = args.slice(1,2).join(' ');
    var query = "SELECT * FROM test where membername=" + mysql.escape(name);
    con.query(query, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    });


}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "dbreturn"
}
```

But the  result I'm getting is just: []

Thanks! Hopefully there will be someone who can help me... :)

Comment: Try logging the query variable and querying it manually on the db and check if it will return any values.

Comment: that didn't work :(

Comment: Why not? Can you explain how it didn't work?

Comment: it shows the same: []